# Passing param values to redirect_to as querystring in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, query-string

This should be simple, but I can't seem to find an easy answer.

How can I pass param values from the current request into a redirect_to call?  I have some form values I'd like to pass into the query string of a GET redirect

I'd like to do something like:

```
redirect_to @thing, :foo => params[:foo]
```

and get sent to:

```
http://things/4?[foo][key1]=val1&[foo][key2]=val2
```

Thanks!

Also - how could this be handled for a redirect_to :back?

```
redirect_to :back, :foo => params[:foo]
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The 'Record' form of [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000637) uses the second argument only for the response status.  You'll have to use another form of redirect_to, like the 'String' form.  e.g.:

```
redirect_to thing_path(@thing, :foo => params[:foo])
```

which will work for nested `params[:foo]` params like you mentioned.  Or, as Drew commented below, you can use [polymorphic_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) (or _path):

```
redirect_to polymorphic_path(@thing, :foo => params[:foo])
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to Jordan's answer:

If you don't know what type of object `@thing` might be, you can use the universal `polymorphic_url` method.  This is the method that is called internally when you pass in an object to `redirect_to` anyway.